# Rails 4 - vendor assets fonts file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, vendor

I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate a wrap bootstrap file into my rails 4 app.

I have a folder in my vendor assets called fonts.

In it I have several files on is called the following:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff"):
```

I my vendor/assets/stylesheets, I have a file called simple-line-icons.css, which has:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';
    src:url('vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot');
    src:url('vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.svg#Simple-Line-Icons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When i save everything, and precompile assets, my console error log shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Can anyone see what needs to happen to get this to work?

**Taking the suggestion below, I now have:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';
    /*src:url('vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot');*/
    src:asset-url("fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot");
    src:asset-url("fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
    asset-url("fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff") format('woff'),
    asset-url("fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf") format('truetype'),
    asset-url("fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.svg#Simple-Line-Icons") format('svg');
```

inside simple-line-icons.css.erb

but i still get 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `.erb` to the end of your css file, then change `url('vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot')` to `asset-url("fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot")` and same as the others. I think the problem is after you precompile the file, rails will add a random token to the file such as `"/assets/application-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.js"`, so if you are using `'vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot'`, you cannot find the file.

## update

change your `simple-line-icons.css.erb` file to `simple-line-icons.scss` then

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'simple-line-icons';
  src: asset-url('Simple-Line-Icons.eot?v=2.2.2');
  src: asset-url('Simple-Line-Icons.eot?v=2.2.2#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), asset-url('Simple-Line-Icons.ttf?v=2.2.2') format('truetype'), asset-url('Simple-Line-Icons.woff2?v=2.2.2') format('woff2'), asset-url('Simple-Line-Icons.woff?v=2.2.2') format('woff'), asset-url('Simple-Line-Icons.svg?v=2.2.2#simple-line-icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

at the end in your `application.css` file add the following:

```
*= require simple-line-icons
```

because apparently require_tree . will not require the file in your vendor and lib folder

Comment: hi, I tried this, and show that attempt above. I still get 404 errors on the files

Comment: are you under production mode or development mode?

Comment: is the 404 message still the same? because in your original post `http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor/assets/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` is obviously a wrong path

Comment: the message is the same